# Spring security authenticaton

Tags: spring-security

I'm developing an application based on Spring and I'm using Spring Security 3.1.3.
Every time i try to authenticate, authentication doesn't succeed. Here is my security-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true">
<security:form-login login-page="/app/main"
default-target-url="/app/account" />
<security:logout logout-url="/app/logout"
logout-success-url="/app/main" />
</security:http>

<bean id="passwordEncoder"
class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt. BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<security:authentication-provider
user-service-ref="userService" >
<security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
class="org.springframework.security.authentication .dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
<property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
<property name="hideUserNotFoundExceptions" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationManager"
class="org.springframework.security.authentication .ProviderManager">
<constructor-arg>
<ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
</constructor-arg>
</bean>


</beans>
```

In my bean's password set method, i use BCryptPasswordEncoder like following:

```
public void setPassword(String password) {
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder= new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
this.password=passwordEncoder.encode(password);
}
```

I store username and encoded password in db. I can authenticate just the first time after i sign up. Reason for that is that hibernate entity manager does automatic update of password value in database after selection. I don't know why!!! When i use plain text password, none of this is happening, everything works fine.

Comment: As spring namespace config already registers authenticationManager as provider manager, do not define bean for authenticationManagaer explicitly. Yuo can simply add <security:authentication-provider
ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to know for sure, since you haven't elaborated on what "my bean" is or where this `setPassword` function is used, but if it's part of a Hibernate entity, then it may be called with an already encoded password (e.g. when loading an entity from the database, not just when creating a new). You certainly wouldn't want to use bcrypt at that point. This might also explain why you can login the first time and sounds likely from your description of hibernate automatically updating the field.

For testing purposes, try adding an assertion that checks that the string doesn't begin with "$2a" (as a bcrypt string will), and throw an exception if it does.

If that's the case, make sure you call the encoder outside the entity when you create it, and pass in the encoded password to the setter.