# Spring AuthenticationManagerBuilder Password Hashing

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm trying to set up user authentication in Spring, but after adding password hashing it doesn't authenticate. I am using Spring Boot and Spring Security.

Here is a shortened version of my code:

Customer entity:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

  private String username;
  private String password;

  public Customer() {
  }

  @Column
  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  @Column(length=100)
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public String setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(password);
  }
}
```

Security configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().
            httpBasic().and().
            csrf().disable();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService() {

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            Customer customer = customerRepository.findByUsername(username);
            if(user != null) {
                return new User(username, customer.getPassword(), true, true, true, true,
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"));
            } else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("could not find the user '"
                        + username + "'");
            }
        }
    };
}
}
```

Like I said, if I remove the password encoder (from both the AuthenticationManagerBuilder and the Customer entity), entering the username and password will authenticate. But, when I add the BCryptPasswordEncoder, it does not authenticate, and no error message is given.

Comment: Do not encode the password in the set method of your Entity. you only need to do this on creat new user . Spring security will deal with the rest

Comment: @bwright : it seems you have an actual answer to this question, you should publish as such (not as a comment).

Comment: This looks like the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17908831/241990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not encode the password in the set method of your Entity. you only need to do this on creat new user . Spring security will deal with the rest

Comment: This did work, however the password is now being stored in the database as plaintext. Do you know how I can store a hashed password?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I just hash the password in the constructor. Thank you for the help.